QGIS expression builder @input_raster returns gibberish filenames
The title says it all: When I want to build a batch expression and use @INPUT_RASTER to build the filename, I get a long string at the end of the original filename.
Example:
I have a tiff file called "conflict4.tif" I am adding it by using @INPUT_RASTER in the expression builder but it returns: 'conflict4_eaa016b1_6edc_4776_b333_025027d0d40c'.
I am attaching a screenshot.
How can I only return "conflict4"?


Please specify what QGIS's tool exactly are you using.

Zonal Statistics -> Run as batch process -> Filename -> Build Expression

What you are seeing is the layer ID. It is a unique identifier for the layer that ensures it can be refered to unambiguously if two or more layers have the same name. Moreover, the layer ID will persist as long as the layer remains in the project, even if the layer name or data source is changed. This guarantees consistency by ensuring that expressions do not need to be updated if the layer's name is changed, for example.
You can get the layer name (conflict4) by calling the layer_property function and passing 'name' as the property argument:
layer_property(@INPUT_RASTER, property:='name')

Or the filepath of the layer's data source:
layer_property(@INPUT_RASTER, property:='path')


Dear Matt, thank you that worked!
